# Cutom batch actions on sonata admin

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin

I am working with sonata admin bundle of symfony.
Is there any way to show Modal on click of OK of batch actions?

For example in this image:

[image]

When I click on Ok after selected elements a modal should open.
Is there any custom way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try to overrride the default edit view

```
# config/packages/sonata_admin.yaml

sonata_admin:
    templates:
        edit:  '@SonataAdmin/CRUD/edit.html.twig'
```

This `@SonataAdmin/CRUD/edit.html.twig` is the default edit template used by sonata. You might be able to replace it by whatever you want. Then, adding the modal shouldn't be different than what you might already be used to do in front.